# Number of ways of forming groups.

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

There are 30 members, and you have to divide them into two groups, each consisting of at least one member. Find the number of ways of doing this.

I am unsure what the correct answer is, but I think it is the sum of the number of ways of selecting 1, 2, 3,...29 members from 30. It would be helpful if someone could verify and possibly provide a more structured answer.

Comment: This is not a homework question. This was asked in an online assessment interview, but I am not sure if my answer was correct, and I won't get feedback from the interview.

Comment: That is right. And when you add it up, you will get $2^{30}-2$, by the binomial theorem. But we don't actually have to split into cases: picking the first group determines the second, so it's a matter of picking any subset of any size other than 0 or 30. The classic way to do that is to pick yes/no for each member independently, for a total of $2^{30}$, and then in this case subtract $2$ corresponding to either all yesses or all noes.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you need to ask the interviewer whether the groups are labeled or not, to answer correctly.

If the groups are labeled, $2^{30}-2$ which is equivalent to $\sum_{k=1}^{29}\binom{30}{k}$
is the correct answer, but when nothing has been mentioned, we could well assume them to be unlabeled, and then you would need to subtract half of the $\binom{30}{15}$ group , since everyone in the $15-15$ division would be counted twice, thus the answer would be $2^{30}-2 -\binom{30}{15}/2$

I guess the expected answer would be $2^{30}-2$, but someone who at least  raised the question of labeling and the difference it would make, might get some extra brownie points !

Comment: Is the answer clear ?